# 'Initializer element is not a compile-time constant' when assigning a variable

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50, initializer

I'm trying to run this code but on the terminal it says 'initializer element is not a compile-time constant:

[image]

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
int i = get_int ('first population: ')
int j = get_int ('second population: ')
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: Seriously... how to write main() is usually shown on the very first pages of any C programming book. You can't just type random stuff in the source editor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Read closely the early chapters of your learning material.

- you didn't put `;`s at the end of your statements
- your `main` function's body is not enclosed within `{}`
- Your strings are not enclosed within `""`.

You want this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i = get_int ("first population: ");
  int j = get_int ("second population: ");
  ...
  more code
  ...
}
```